# How to test game created w/ LibGDX and Android Studio on iOS

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, macos, libgdx

I have made a game using LibGDX and Android Studio on windows but I want to test it on iOS, I know I need a Mac to do this so I am currently using VirtualBox to emulate this. I have downloaded eclipse but I am having problems importing the project. It is looking for the SDK in the same location as Windows and I presume this is because of the android studio properties files. Anyways, how would I test this game on an iOS device and if it is via eclipse on mac, how can I import my android studio game into eclipse?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you are looking for is something like [RoboVM](http://robovm.com/). LibGDX supports RoboVM to build apps for iOS. I actually used once on Eclipse but looks like they released a plugin for Android Studio too. Check this out: [RoboVM Android Studio Plugin](https://robovm.com/intellij-ideaandroid-studio-robovm-plugin-released/)

Comment: I understand that, I should already have that, but how do I actually test it now